# Retrieve the Window Title using Com4J

Tags: java, window, title, com4j

I have a MS Office bridge using COM4J in a java application and I am trying to retrieve the window title of a word application.

There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time trying do this, I did not find any solution. I change my solution and solve the problem using another way.